# Main Thread Blocked by File Uploading in WebKit Directory Input

Tags: javascript, html

When attempting to upload a large number of files (not necessarily large in size, but in terms of quantity) via a **Web Kit Directory** type input in the browser (not on the server), the main thread becomes blocked, causing the UI to freeze. How can I move this file uploading process to a worker thread?

I’ve searched extensively, but most of the information I find relates to server-side issues related to file size, not the number of files being uploaded in the browser.